# fill array with random but unique numbers in C#

Tags: c#

Okay I know there are few posts like this but I need to use only loops (for,do,while) and if, else to fill array with random but unique numbers so how shall i edit this code

```
        int[] x = new int[10];
        Random r = new Random();

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.Length; i++) {

            x[i] = r.Next(10);
            Console.WriteLine("x[{0}] = {1}", i, x[i]);
        }
```

Comment: "Random but unique" - that's not random :)

Comment: so I mean that when i randomize it wont repeat i used r.next(10) just because it was easier to spot whether it repeats or not so it shiuld use each number only once

Comment: If you have a target array length of 10, and only want numbers up to 10, then you actually just want to shuffle the array `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. And that’s explained in the linked question.

Comment: no i need to increase random generated numbers limit from 0,100 i used 10 on code now just so it was easier that it doesn't repeat

Comment: Is 100 the final upper limit? Then create an array from 0…100, shuffle that, and take the first 10 numbers. That’s still more efficient than generating random numbers while checking all the time whether you already had that one or not.

Comment: You could come up with something more interesting for daily question... (previous http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35965056/fill-array-with-random-but-unique-numbers-in-c-sharp link for 10K+) - you really should put at least some effort in doing your homework/entertainment project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the newly generated number already exists in the array, if not then add it to the array, if yes then generate a new one.

For examle:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] x = new int[10];
        Random r = new Random();

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            var next = 0;                
            while (true)
            {
                next = r.Next(10);
                if (!Contains(x, next)) break;                    
            }

            x[i] = next;
            Console.WriteLine("x[{0}] = {1}", i, x[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static bool Contains(int[] array, int value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] == value) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i do it ?

Comment: This algorithm crashes Unity for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Without checking that generated number is already presented in array you can't to solve this task.

So you must generate new number and before inserting it into array check for uniq.

Comment: how can i check if its unique ? what will the code be